# How to integrate silverlight into aspx? Please explain

Tags: silverlight

I have created a Silverlight application now I want to embed it into my aspx page. Is there any video tutorial for this, which explains how to integrate silverlight in aspx page?

Comment: use Bing for your question, it will reveal plenty for you to try.  If you still cant get what you need, come back here and post what you have tried and re-explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<title>AyarlarSLV</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
          appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
          return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

        errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);
    }
</script>
```

**Silverlight portion :**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Silverlight.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>

</head>
```